# About hibernate inheritace mapping and Discriminator column, how do I know which type of object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In jpa2 inheritance mapping, single table strategy, the discriminator column don't show in enitity object, and implicity mapping with DiscriminatorColumn annotation.

then How do I know which sub object I get?

I expect this:

> if(object.obj_type==1){   }

and also, how do I get discriminator value in runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to have an abstract super class where you define the discriminator column and the sub classes to define the discriminator value.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "_type")
public abstract class AbstractSuperClass {

    @Column(name = "_type", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable = false)
    private String type;    

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(SubClass.TYPE)
public class SomeSubClass extends AbstractSuperClass {

    public static final String TYPE = "SOME_SUBTYPE";
}
```

So basically at runtime you could just check with `instanceof`

```
if(object instanceof SomeSubClass){}
```

Or even with the type value

```
AbstractSuperClass object = ..
if(object.getType() == SomeSubClass.TYPE){}
```